# Getting object value for AJAX call using Dajaxice

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, dajaxice

I have a `Song` model with a `votes` attribute. I have a `Vote as Favourite` button displayed below each `Song` object. I want when a user clicks on the `Vote as Favourite` button the `votes` attribute associated with that `Song` object should increment by 1 and all the `Vote as Favourite` buttons should be disabled.

**HTML**

```
{% for song in dj_song_list %}
    <div>
        <p class="song"><h3><strong>{{ song.name }}</strong></h3></p>
        <p><strong>Artist: </strong>{{ song.artists}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" id='vote' onclick="Dajaxice.hunt.disable_button(Dajax.process)">Vote as Favourite</button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using dajaxice/dajax for my AJAX call. This is what I've come up with as my ajax.py

**ajax.py**

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from dajax.core import Dajax

@dajaxice_register
def disable_button(request):
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.assign('#vote', 'disabled', 'disabled')
    return dajax.json()

@dajaxice_register(method="POST")   
def update_votes(request, song):
    song.votes += 1
    song.save()
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Thank you for voting'})
```

**JS**

```
function callback(data){
    alert(data.message);
}
```

How do I get the value of `Song` object to send to `update_votes()`?

The `disable_button()` disables only the first vote button. How can I disable all the vote buttons?

How can I call both `update_votes()` and `disable_button()` using the same buttons onclick attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can update the votes. You don't need update_votes to be an ajax function.

```
def update_votes(song_id):
    song = Song.objects.get(id=song_id)
    song.votes += 1
    song.save()
```

You can then call this function from within disable_button.

```
@dajaxice_register
def disable_button(request, song_id):
    update_votes(song_id)
    #disable the buttons
    return #whatever
```

And are you sure you're using the right selector to disable your buttons?